# Getting error when trying to run MessageHub Reciever using Java and VCAP_SERVICES

Tags: java, ibm-cloud, message-hub

I have an instance of IBM Message Hub provisioned on Bluemix. I have implemented a Java Receiver running on my local machine that needs to be able to connect to this instance of IBM Message Hub, and receive messages.

How should I set up my VCAP_SERVICES so that I can connect to my IBM Message Hub instance from Bluemix? When I go to the Service Credentials tab, I have one set of credentials configured. The key name is MHCredentials.  The JSON value for it is:

```
{
  "mqlight_lookup_url": "https://mqlight-lookup-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net/Lookup?serviceId=26f5f662-b757-43dc-8fcc-810c8d3fbeec",
  "api_key": "DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
  "kafka_admin_url": "https://kafka-admin-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443",
  "kafka_rest_url": "https://kafka-rest-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:443",
  "kafka_brokers_sasl": [
    "kafka01-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka02-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka03-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka04-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093",
    "kafka05-prod01.messagehub.services.us-south.bluemix.net:9093"
  ],
  "user": "DXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXx",
  "password": "3XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
}
```

Please tell me how my VCAP_SERVICES should be set so that I can connect to MessageHub from my receiver, which is running on my local machine.  I already created an environment variable on my machine called:  VCAP_SERVICES with the JSON string shown above.  However, when I ran my receiver I got an error: `Not a JSON Array`.

Comment: This blog post may be helpful although it mentions kafka 0.9.0 and you should use the current kafka 0.10.0  https://developer.ibm.com/messaging/2016/03/03/message-hub-kafka-java-api/ The blogs suggests you  have a JAAS Login configuration file, example of login configuration file:

KafkaClient {
    com.ibm.messagehub.login.MessageHubLoginModule required
    serviceName="kafka"
    username="username"
    password="password";
};

Answer (score 1):

IBM Messaging has created a tutorial video on how to get started with MessageHub. The video should cover the basics of connecting to the service:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tt-bLtFzC_4

Your "Not a JSON Array" error suggests that somehow your VCAP_SERVICES environment variable is malformed and indeed it is not valid JSON?

You could try to develop a very small application that does nothing else other than printing out the VCAP_SERVICES environment variable. Then you could run it locally on your laptop as well as deploying it into Bluemix to compare the two and see what the difference is?

```
public class VcapPrinter {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String vcapServices = System.getenv("VCAP_SERVICES");
        System.out.println(vcapServices);
    }
}
```

You might need to be slightly cleverer than this and keep the application alive so that you can inspect the STDOUT in Bluemix.